# complete a recursive function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, recursion

I have something like this:

```
function recurse(a){
  for(i = a; i < 3; i++){
    alert(i);
    if(i == 0){
      recurse(++a);
    }
  }
} 
recurse(0);
```

the output that i would expect is 0 (calls the new function) 1, 2 (ends the second function called), and then finishes the first run of the function with 1 and 2.
But instead it only alert 0,1 and 2 once and it finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is global

Try `var i`, and you may get the behavior you're expecting.

```
function recurse(a){
  for(var i = a; i < 3; i++){
    alert(i);
    if(i == 0){
      recurse(++a);
    }
  }
} 
recurse(0);
```

outputs: `0, 1, 2, 1, 2`

the first `1, 2` being from the deeper level of recursion.

As originally written, you'd get `0` from the top level, `1,2` from the deeper level, and then nothing else in the top level (because `i < 3` was no longer satisfied).